# i want my page to scroll only once for for continuous multiple scrolls. below is my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

> i want my page to scroll only once for for continuous multiple scrolls. below is my code?

```
if(w > 1300) {
    $('.scroll-pane').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event, delta) {
        if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0 ) {
            val =this.scrollRight + (delta *433 * 2 );
            jQuery(this).animate({
                  scrollRight: val
            }, 500,'easeOutSine');
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).text('scrolling up !');
        }
        else {
            val = this.scrollLeft - (delta * 433 * 2 );
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                scrollLeft: val
            }, 500,'easeOutSine');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    });
```

Comment: Some parts are missing

Comment: Please, provide a working example, with html, for example using JSFiddle.

Comment: i have used mousewheel.js for horizontal scrolling

Comment: this is my full coding for that @verdesrobert

Comment: @user3513879 Plase post html code

Comment: @user3513879 the value w is also not defined that means it is define somewhere else  please make sure the code you posting helps us reproduce your environment.

Comment: @user3513879 please update this by pasting the html and all you have http://jsfiddle.net/E28RW/

Answer (score 0):

When i said there's a part missing:

```
var w=1500;//this value is added by me, you should post the part that provides this variable's value.

if(w > 1300) {
    $('.scroll-pane').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event, delta) {
        if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0 ) {
            val =this.scrollRight + (delta *433 * 2 );
            jQuery(this).animate({
                  scrollRight: val
            }, 500,'easeOutSine');
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).text('scrolling up !');
        }
        else {
            val = this.scrollLeft - (delta * 433 * 2 );
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                scrollLeft: val
            }, 500,'easeOutSine');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    });
} //this was missing in the original
```

the last line is the one missing for the code to be ok